# What happened to the tailed beasts?

Tags: naruto

This is another one of the questions that kishimoto sensei never actually addressed after the end of the series. It could be natural that they were left alone in forests , but is there any concrete evidence suggesting the same .

What happened to the bijuu's? Are they left alone in the forest or was there equal distribution amongst villages to leverage equal power? If yes , do we know about the existences of jinchuriki's post-naruto other than killer bee and naruto ?

Comment: To clear it up, their chakra was what was left in Naruto. Their physical form is elsewhere and currently unknown but if necessary, Naruto can contact them. `"do we know about the existences of jinchuriki's post-naruto other than killer bee and naruto ?"` We know that jinchurikis are split from the ten tails (a manifestation of a chakra fruit tree) and we know there are other chakra fruits (Momoshiki had a bunch), so other jinchuriki could exist but no other jinchurikis have been confirmed - most tailed beasts are probably free in another unkown (unrevealed) dimension

Comment: I doubt there could be any other Jinchuuriki outside earth @JohnD because firstly, The only reason the God tree became the ten tails was because Kaguya became jealous and wanted to retrieve her chakra from her sons. The chakra of the God tree is usually eaten and it is a pretty rare instance of the God tree taking on a humanoid form (much less being split by another otsutsuki into lesser forms)

Answer (score 1):

In Boruto Episode 55, Urashiki spoke to Momoshiki Otsutsuki about the existence of 9 massive entities of Chakra in the form of tailed beasts. However, the only tailed beasts whose locations he explicitly mentioned were the Hachibi and Kyuubi. Urashiki was the  member that the Main Branch of the Otsutsuki Clan, who was tasked with searching for the Chakra fruit that Kaguya was originally tasked with, and with his Byakugan senses he was only able to detect the Eight and Nine tails.

My Hypothesis is that; if the tailed beasts were somewhere in the open forest, then Urashiki would most definitely have mentioned them and then started with the  lesser beasts which would be easier to acquire, but rather he does not mention them at all. This could Imply that the Tailed beasts are somewhere where even Urashiki could not find. I would guess that they were hidden somewhere where No one would try to Harm or take advantage of their Chakra.

Answer (score -1):

they are alive and are in the forest, since no one will want to capture tailed beasts for wars after fighting as one during fourth war. naruto wouldn't let them be captured since he promsied to set the tailed beast free

Comment: Do you have any source or is that plain speculation

Comment: its a plain talk try reasoning it yourself, since naruto promised the tailed beast that he would set them free, do you think he will just stay put to allow someone recapture them

Comment: it's not about recapturing them , its about the tailed beasts themselves being accustomed to things too . Like shukaku may have liked staying within gaara itself .